# Are reflexive modules closed under extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Is it true that $\text{Ext}^1(M,A)=0$ for any reflexive $A$-module $M$? Here $A$ is a nice enough ring. (It is a finite type algebra over a field and is regular and also a domain) I want to know whether in a short exact sequence if the kernel and cokernel are reflexive then is the extension also reflexive?

Comment: Take $A=k[x,y,z]$ and $M=Ae_1\oplus Ae_2\oplus Ae_3/xe_1+ye_2+ze_3$. Then the ext you want is not zero even though $M$ is reflexive.

Comment: I see. It seems reflexive sheaves are closed under extension over regular rings, although the ext might not vanish.